# Golang - embed.FS pass argument

Tags: go

I need to modify fragment of code which needs to take argument instead of use hardcoded path in `go:embed`

My code:

```golang
package main

import (
    "embed"
    "log"
    
    "github.com/golang-migrate/migrate/v4/source/iofs"
)

// Instead of use hardcoded `migrations/*.sql` I need to pass 
// `path` to `migrations/*.sql` as a argument to `migrate` function
//go:embed migrations/*.sql
var fs embed.FS

func main() {
    const path = "migrations/*.sql"
    if err := migrate(path); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("done")
}

func migrate(path string) error {
    d, err := iofs.New(fs, "migrations")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // rest of the code...
    return nil
}
```

I already tried to use `os.DirFS` however result of this function only contains data with `dir` parameter without actual files from folder `migrations/*.sql`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the question. You've created an embedded filesystem that contains multiple files (everything matching `*.sql` in the `migrations` directory). You can load files from this embedded filesystem by name.

Let's assume that your `migrations` directory looks like:

```
migrations/
├── bar.sql
└── foo.sql
```

Where `foo.sql` contains `this is foo.sql`, and similarly for `bar.sql`.

If we write code like this:

```
func main() {
  const path = "migrations/foo.sql"
  if err := migrate(path); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  log.Println("done")
}

func migrate(path string) error {
  data, err := fs.ReadFile(path)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  fmt.Println(string(data))

  // rest of the code...
  return nil
}
```

You'd get the output:

```
this is foo.sql
```

If you want to iterate over files in your embedded filesystem, you can use the `ReadDir` method:

```
func main() {
  const path = "migrations"
  if err := migrate(path); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
  }
  log.Println("done")
}

func migrate(path string) error {
  items, err := fs.ReadDir(path)
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  for _, ent := range items {
    fmt.Println(ent.Name())
  }

  // rest of the code...
  return nil
}
```

This would print:

```
bar.sql
foo.sql
```

Does that help?

Comment: Why would you panic-on-error in a function that returns an `error` value?

Comment: Because I'm lazy and was writing quickly. I'm not demonstrating error handling; I'm demonstrating file access in an embedded filesystem. I mean, good catch, but...meh.

Comment: I think it's acceptable to panic here, as an embedded asset file path should always exist. Errors should cover temporal issues like `500` system unavailable, or `400` bad user requests etc. A missing build asset will always be missing, so the error should be more severe i.e. a panic.